# What does the expression () -> () = {} mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, closures

I'm going over some `Swift` code and I've encounter this function signature:

```
func foo(withCompletion completion: @escaping () -> () = {}) { ... }
```

I'm not sure what does the part  `() -> () = {}` mean?
And if it's a default value, how should it be used?

Any idea?

The code is in `Swift 3`

Comment: It is a function that returns void. The function in this case being `{}` empty. Doesn't do anything by default. You can add a callback function as long as it returns void.

Comment: ...and takes no arguments.

Comment: It could probably be refactored to be an optional and set to nil, instead of an empty closure implementation.

Comment: This would have been clearer `@escaping () -> Void = {}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `completion` argument has a type of `() -> ()`. That's a closure that has no parameters and has an empty (void) return type.

The `= {}` is the default value for the parameter meaning that you don't actually need to pass in a closure if you don't need one.

So you can call this as:

```
foo(withCompletion: {
    // your code here
})
```

or (using trailing closure syntax):

```
foo() {
    // your code here
}
```

or (if you don't want to use the completion closure):

```
foo()
```